# Validating downloaded image

Tags: ruby, image, download, corruption, corrupt-data

This downloads image to a disk:

```
image = open permalink_url, "rb", &:read
...
File.binwrite "images/#{hash}", image
```

Sometimes it comes corrupted:

[image]

while there was **no exception**.

1. How do I check if the image has been downloaded correctly (to otherwise retry the procedure)?
2. How much is it ok, that there was no exception? How did it happen? Was the network exception silenced on some intermediate server?

UPD: Imagemagick says [`identify` "reports if an image is incomplete or corrupt"](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) but it does not:

```
$ identify temp.png
temp.png PNG 1080x1080 1080x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.126MB 0.000u 0:00.049
```

Here are two corrupted images:

1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3BLwu7Vb2U-MnNqdHV4MzFSX2s/view?usp=sharing
2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3BLwu7Vb2U-d3Fab2lmT1hvZlE/view?usp=sharing

UPD: I redownloaded the image and did some analysis -- the bad variation has 300000 extra bytes somewhere in the middle broken in a lot of pieces. Garbage is not just 0x00 but looks random.

Comment: Do you have the file size available in a table? Perhaps you could compare against that as a first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the image handling gems, e.g. `chunky_png`:

```
require 'chunky_png'
begin
  ChunkyPNG::Datastream.from_file('bad.png')
rescue ChunkyPNG::CRCMismatch
  puts "png corrupted!"
end
```

**Edit**: `Datastream` is more efficient than `Image` in this case.

**Edit 2**: If you want to be able to validate any format that ImageMagick can handle and don't mind calling external binaries, this should work:

```
unless system('identify', '-verbose', 'bad.jpg', out: IO::NULL, err: IO::NULL)
  puts "the file can't be opened or is corrupted"
end
```

Comment: I'll give it a try on Monday. But there could be also JPG, BMP or whatever the user uploads.

Comment: You can use any of the gems that use ImageMagick. Note that while `identify` doesn't report corruptions, you'll get an error message when you e.g. try to `convert` the image to another format.

Comment: Thanks! The `identify` with `-verbose` works perfectly.